# There is a new relic clone for arm (Raspberry PI)?

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, newrelic, raspbian

I need to monitor the performance of a raspberry PI (with raspbian), I tried to use new relic, but it doesn't support ARM architecture, so it's impossible to use.

I even tried graphdat but seems to have the same problem.

Any alternative to suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

Linode Longview does support arm architecture:

https://www.linode.com/longview

The free tier have 12-hour retention but that may be enough for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but New Relic has ARM and ARM64 infrastructure agents now:
https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/binaries/linux/arm/

I've tested this on a Raspberry Pi 4 (8GB) on Debian (32-bit) and it's been working fine so far.

In case anyone else tries, here's what I did:

Download the Infrastructure Agent:

```
sudo curl https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/binaries/linux/arm/newrelic-infra_linux_1.20.5_arm.tar.gz --output newrelic-infra_linux_1.20.5_arm.tar.gz
```

Extract the files

```
sudo tar -xf newrelic-infra_linux_1.20.5_arm.tar.gz
```

Add license key to the config script:

```
echo "license_key=\"<YOUR_LICENSE_KEY>\"" | sudo tee -a ~/newrelic-infra/config_defaults.sh
```

Install the Infrastructure Agent

```
sudo ~/newrelic-infra/installer.sh
```

Check service status to make sure it's running:

```
sudo systemctl status newrelic-infra
```

---

By default, process information is not sent to New Relic, so I had to enable it manually:

```
echo "enable_process_metrics: true" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
```

Finally, restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart newrelic-infra
```